# Voltage of Incandescent Christmas Mini Bulbs

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I'm in dire need of help!

It appears that for a string of 35 incandescent mini bulbs, the bulbs are rated at 3.5V (125V / 35 = 3.5V). A string of 50 has a rating of 2.5V (125V / 50 = 2.5V). Thus, if you install a bulb from a 35 string into a 50 string that bulb will be significantly brighter.

It appears that a string of 100 also may be rated at 2.5V and not (125V / 100 = 1.25). My problem is I have two large outdoor light trees, each tree has 1000 bulbs. The tree is designed into 4 separate plugged sections, but I'm not sure how many bulbs are in each section.

I have tried replacing burnt out bulbs with ones from light strings of 100, but because I believe they are rated at 2.5V they're significantly brighter and burn out within a week. I'm running out of the proper replacements. Is there a way to lower the voltage of each independent tree section in order that I may use the 2.5V bulbs as replacements?

Comment: FYI: 35 bulb strings (or multiples of 35 bulbs, 70, etc) use 3.5 V bulbs. 50 bulb strings (or multiples of 50 bulbs, 100, 150, etc) use 2.5 V bulbs.

Comment: You are assuming they are all rated for the same current. That may not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to wire an incandescent lamp in series with your lights. The smaller the wattage, the higher the resistance and the more voltage drop you'll get. The problem is that the string lights require very little current. It's an easy one to try. When you connect everything up measure the voltage across the Christmas lights to see if you think you've reduced it enough.

The second option is to use a transformer to reduce the voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flBTBz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Using a 12 V transformer to reduce mains voltage.*

By wiring the transformer as shown the 12 V winding subtracts from the mains. This will give you a 10% reduction in voltage. If you can find a 24 V transformer you could get 20%. You don't need much power so something like a doorbell transformer might be adequate.

You need a multimeter to test this before connecting the lights. Measure the output voltage on V AC range. If you've connected the secondary correctly the output will be V<sub>primary</sub> - V<sub>secondary</sub>. If you wire it backwards you'll get more like V<sub>primary</sub> + V<sub>secondary</sub>. Obviously it would not be a good idea to connect them up in this configuration.

Comment: Really clever trick!

Comment: Yea. This is pretty badass.  I never would’ve thought of it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it would be to get the right bulbs. With a quick search I found 3.5 V bulbs, pack of 50 for $8 US.

If you insist on lowering the voltage you could use a resistor, to replace 3.5 V bulbs with 2.5 V bulbs you'd want to drop 1 V per bulb (and you'd have to replace all of the bulbs in a string, you can't mix them). Then you need to know the current, let's say they're 100 mA, that would be \$35V/0.1A = 350\Omega\$ and it would dissipate 3.5 W so you'd need at least a 5 W resistor, 10 W would be better.

You might also try rectifying the voltage, this is what those [light dimmer discs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rBQZi-fPs8) that went in the old incandescent light sockets were, big diodes. It basically chops off half the AC waveform. A 1N4007 diode in series might bring the voltage down enough. Doing a quick simulation with an AC voltage of 117 VRMS I get 83 VRMS with a diode in line, which is what I expected, RMS times 0.707 (1 over the square root of 2). That should give you just under 2.4 V per bulb.

Comment: And what about the flickering?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Flickering? They're incandescent, they're pretty slow to respond.

Comment: As I recall, there was some 50 Hz flickering on the lower power light bulbs. But for Christmas lights, it probably won't annoy.  Otherwise a clever idea because no power is dissipated...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist They're Christmas lights, flickering is a feature :D

Comment: The 60Hz flickering on LED Christmas lights is really bad and even my normie family members see it. I never tried with incandescents, so now I’m curious. Might have to rig one up and do a test myself…